# how to use glimpse with petapoco?

Tags: petapoco, glimpse

I installed [this plugin](http://nuget.org/packages/PetaPoco.Glimpse) from nuget.

I enabled glimpse through the glimpse.axd file but when I go to the petapoco tab I see this message

```
"No database requests or database logging not switched on (Compilation debug='true' or ForceLogging='true' on PetaPoco.DatabaseWithLogging)"
```

where do I set this logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `DatabaseWithProfiling()` not `Database()` as you normally would. Checkout out the code in the Model folder after you have pulled it down from NuGet.